# How can I create an extension which calls the Youtube API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have created, on my computer, a Chrome extension which calls the YouTube API and shows extra information about video search results. In the extension I use an API token provided.

The extension works, but I am wondering how to prevent future users of the extension to retrieve my API token by decompiling the extension (which is only JavaScript and config files) and use this token outside of the scope the extension ? If it happened the API usage quota could be exhausted quite quickly and then the extension would be unusable for the other users of the extension.

Comment: [There's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_API_Keys) only protection by domain or by a iOS/Android app id.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the info. But surely there are existing browser extensions that use some of the Google APIs, how do they handle this issue ?

Comment: Well, examine their source code. I guess they don't care that much.